# codeigniter password protect directory with cpanel

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel, password-protection

i want to protect my admin panel with password protect directory in cpanel. 
The directory structure is;

- application

  - controller

    - admin.php(load admin directory in view)
  - views

    - admin(directory)
    - bla.php
  - models

i want to protect admin directory in views and i set a password in cpanel but it doesn't work correctly. 
when i reached www.blabla.com/admin it doesn't work, when i reached www.blabla.com/application/views/admin it works.
how can i solve it?

note: i removed index.php via .htaccess

Comment: I have exactly the same question

Answer (score 1):

**By Adding**

```
<?
ob_start();
$auth =1;
$name='user'; 
$pass='password';
if($auth == 1) {
if ( (!$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']==$name) or (!$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']==$pass))
{
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Powered By 404 Error"');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
exit("Access not allowed.");
}
}
?>
```

into admin.php

be careful you need to remove the `?>` and `<?` from the code